# How to write SQL query for the ColdFusion FindNoCase If condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

I would like to write this below query as a stored procedure in SQL. When doing so, I am unable to find out, how to write for one of the condition written in ColdFusion that is:

```
<CFIF FINDNOCASE("TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES", ORDER.USERSORT)>
  , ISNULL(CPL.TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES, 0) AS TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES
</CFIF>
```

I want to make the select statement to be stored procedure that is cfquery tag in the full code section. Thank you.

Full code:

```
<cffunction name="Get" output="false" access="public" returntype="struct">
<cfargument name="orderBy" required="false" type="string" default="lastName, firstName" hint="Valid Columns:firstName, lastName, contactTypeName, classification, title, email, phone, fax, isActive, insertedBy, modifiedBy" />

<cfscript>
    var returnStruct = StructNew();
    var qRates = "";
    var qTotalRecords = "";
    var order = structNew();
    var queryOrderBy = "c.customer_name";
    var endRow = arguments.startRow + arguments.rowLimit - 1;
    var validArgs = false;
    var i="";

    for(i in arguments){
        arguments[i] = Trim(arguments[i]);
    }

    order.userSort = arguments.orderBy;
    order.defaultSort = "c.customer_name";

    order.CUSTOMER_NAME="c.CUSTOMER_NAME";
    order.CUSTOMER_NUMBERsupplierName="c.CUSTOMER_NUMBER";
    order.TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES="ISNULL(cpl.TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES, 0)";     
</cfscript>

<cfquery name="qRates" datasource="#variables.dsn#">

   SELECT customer_name,
          customername,
          customer_number,
          NC_ORIGIN = LEFT( dp.ORIGIN,2)
          <cfif FindNoCase("totalcustomerprofiles", order.userSort)>
          , ISNULL(cpl.TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES, 0) AS TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES</cfif>

   FROM 
          TableName

   SET NOCOUNT OFF
</cfquery>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Changing the number of columns returned would either require dynamic sql or some sort of IF statement hack - neither of which I'd recommend. Why not just include the column in the results and let the front end code decide whether or not to display it?

Comment: But I have to make this cfquery to be store proc so that I do not have inline queries on the UI or front end.

Comment: @Shaw, I think the naming does not impact, Get is the name of the function that I am using here only but in the project I have different name. And related to cold fusion version,  it is 2018.0.0.310739

Comment: @Shawn, I have queries in the front end that's why trying to create Store Proc and calling it from the front end. Thank you.

Comment: version of SQL@Shawn, do you need that one as well???

Comment: All of my comments on this thread are gone? Hmmm.... anyway, yes, what version of SQL are you using? For this query, it probably shouldn't matter, but version can determine if any features are available.

Comment: *"so that I do not have inline queries on the UI*" If you're trying to protect against sql injection, a stored procedure isn't necessary for that (and in this case may even complicate things further IMO).  It can be done with a properly constructed cfquery.  Can you provide an example of what you mean by inline queries?

Comment: If you don't want an inline query in the UI, why not write the queries in a CFC and call that?

Comment: From the partial query, looks like they're already doing that ..somewhat. Would really help to see the full query and a description of the goal though...

Answer (score 0):

I think a way to do this would be with a parameter of the stored procedure.
Add a new parameter for your stored proc, let's say, TOTALCUSTOMERPROFILES (as a boolean). Inside that stored procedure, add or not the column based on the value of that parameter.

When using the cfstoredproc tag to call it, you can specify cfprocparam with a value.
Have the CFIF with a proper true or false depending on the result.

```
<!--- Concept of the call --->
<cfstoredproc ....>
  <cfif FindNoCase("totalcustomerprofiles", order.userSort)>
     <cfprocparam ...  value="true">
  <cfelse>
     <cfprocparam ...  value="false">
  </cfif>
</cfstoredproc>
```

I would suggest, like the other comments, to simply always return the column and have the IF in the output or the result, much easier.
Hope it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: True, but it sounded like the real question was about how to convert the SQL query into a SQL stored procedure, not just pass in parameters. If their reason for doing all of this is to protect against SQL injection, it's much easier to modify an secure the cfquery IMO. With this kind of dynamic statement, stored procedures can actually make things more difficult (complex sql), not to mention more risky as they often require EXEC.

Comment: I totally agree with you :)